# how and why to update web applications?

Tags: java, web-applications, java-6, java-5

Why should we update an application running on Java 1.5 when Java1.6 has replaced Java 1.5 ?How do we do it?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually Java 5 will reach end of life. That would be a good reason to start running it on Java 6 instead.

Also it'd be smart to target the platform with the largest audience, I'd suppose.

Many applications run fine on both platforms. If your app is depending on a discontinued feature in Java 5 I'd consider rewriting it to support future Java platforms.

How to do it? Are you sure you need to do anything at all? Unless it's using disconntinued api's a simple recompile would do ... at most. Also be aware of any warnings about using deprecated api's.  They may disappear in a future version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask anyone who is telling you to use Java 5.0. If that is the only supported Java version for your application, you may have to use it.

You should probably take Java 6 (this is likely to be the best choice).

Java 7 is likely to be released this year and if you have an application which won't be released for some time, you could develop it using Java 7 from the start.

However if the application works and you don't need to change it why not just leave it as is.

It depends on your situation and your requirements as to what is the best version to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to keep the runtime up-to-date on the target machine. Amongst other things there are security implications of running old versions. This probably won't require you to touch your code at all. It might be that you've used a API that has been dropped or you've relied on behaviour that was deemed to be a bug/security flaw, but I think those circumstances are relatively rare.

As to whether you update your development environment to use the latest JDK, it depends on whether you want to use the latest features, etc. And bearing in mind that an old JVM may not be able to run code compiled against a more recent version of Java.